# Unsubscribing event handlers using GetInvocationList

Tags: c#, events, memory-leaks, event-handling, robustness

I have some events in my base class that I want to apply the following pattern to within IDisposable or in the Finalizer.

```
var onCategorizedMessage = this.OnCategorizedMessage.GetInvocationList().ToList();
foreach (var item in onCategorizedMessage)
    this.OnCategorizedMessage -= item;
```

I would repeat this code once per event.

Is this a reasonable and robust way of handling unsubscribing from Events to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: In many cases it's not really a problem.  Is the producer going to out-live the consumer?

Comment: @BryanCrosby - I don't know.  I'm creating a HubTransport Agent and don't know what will happen inside the hosting code.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877026(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Logically, I would think that unsubscribing is the responsibility of the unsubscriber itself. Other than that, there isn't much point in clearing the invocation list when disposing. There IS, however, a BIG point in unsubscribing from an event (from the unsubscriber itself) when it is disposed (To prevent the invocation list of the event having a delegate to a method of a disposed object).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do it using `for` or `foreach`, since you have access to the backing field (that stores the delegates) you just need to do like this:

```
this.OnCategorizedMessage = null;
```

For more information you can check here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/864690/Simplifying-Events-in-NET